# action theme mailchimp subscriber fields

Tags: php, actions, plugin-mailchimp

I'm running the Action wordpress Theme. One of the widget that can be used to sign up users to a mailchimp list.

The thing is, there are only 2 fields to fill in. Name and email.

Now the list has multiple merge fields, but the because the form only has a 'name' field, it fills the users full name in the 'First name' field on mailchimp.

I'm trying to create another field for last names that will fill in the 'last name' field on mailchimp.

I found the php file responsible for the mailchimp subscription widget.

Here's the code

```
<div class=" mailchimp-inner-wrap">

    <form class="clearfix">
        <div class="input-area clearfix">
            <div><input type="text" class='m-name' value="" placeholder="<?php _e("Enter Name","ioa") ?>"><span><?php _e("required",'ioa') ?></span></div>
            <div><input type="text" class='m-email'  value="" placeholder="<?php _e("Enter Email","ioa") ?>"><span><?php _e("required",'ioa') ?></span></div>
            <input type="hidden" class='m-api' value="<?php echo esc_attr($w['mail_api']) ?>">
            <input type="hidden" class='m-list' value="<?php echo esc_attr($w['mail_list']) ?>">
        </div>
        <a href="" class="mailchimp-subscribe"><?php _e("Subscribe","ioa") ?></a>
    </form>
    <div class="mailchimp-subscription-confirmation">
        <?php echo  $w['mail_message'] ?>
    </div>


</div>
```

I've tried copying creating another `input` for last name, but it's not putting the last name in the last name field on mailchimp.

Any ideas?